# Synchronize Printf between two threads

Tags: c, linux, process, synchronization, mutex

I'm trying to understand how these things work. I'm studying for an exam, but my university don't really explain things clearly.

I'm trying to syncrhonize two processes. I started with a simple code that (should) print the PID of the two processes. To be sure they are really syncrhonized, I made it up so that each process print it's PID 5 times and then start again.

This is the code (sorry, I'm using a VM so it's a pain to copy/paste it)

[img]https://i.ibb.co/55vL8vH/code.png[/img]

And this is the result:

[img]https://i.ibb.co/7VZVPdp/result.png[/img]

As you can see, it's a very simple code, but I don't really know why it doesn't work. I guess (but I'm not sure) that this is why the mutex is not shared between the two processes ... it's like each process has it's own Mutex and doesn't cooperate with the other one.

Comment: Do not post code as pictures. If you can't be bothered to type in manually, how can you expect people to bother to help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a very important and wide concept in operating systems but I can show you some tip so you can search furthermore:

when you fork() in your code OS makes a new memory block for the new process that is a copy of parent process memory it means variables are same but if you change one of them in the other process it won't change, you have to use [inter-process communication](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inter-process-communication-ipc/#:%7E:text=Inter%20process%20communication%20(IPC)%20is,Shared%20Memory) concept for [shared memory](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ipc-shared-memory/) in order to have a shared variable between your processes.

Comment: I see.
I was hoping that pthread_mutex_t varibles already have some IPC functions integrated, since their goal was synchronization.

Thank you for your answer :)